# how to use gdb in multiple files in open source

Tags: c, trie

i am trying to gdb trietool to understand trietool source code.But it always failed to gdb.

step as below:
(1)./configure CFLAGS=-g
(2)make

and then `cd /mnt/hgfs/code/libdatrie-0.2.5/tools,ls -lrt`
and `gdb trietool-0.2`,it will report error as below

```
/mnt/hgfs/code/libdatrie-0.2.5/tools/trietool-0.2": not in executable format:
```

and `gdb trietool-0.2.o`,it is ok,and then type command b ../datrie/trie.c:289,it report

```
(gdb) b ../datrie/trie.c:289
No source file named ../datrie/trie.c.
```

But in fact there is trie.c file in datrie dir.

How to fix this issue to get gdb work?Do i miss sth?

Why gdb trietool-0.2 is not ok?

```
milan@milan:/mnt/hgfs/code/libdatrie-0.2.5/tools$ file trietool-0.2
trietool-0.2: Bourne-Again shell script text executable

/mnt/hgfs/code/libdatrie-0.2.5/tools$ file trietool.o
trietool.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Comment: if libdatrie is a library(.a or .so) then you need to write a sample test program to gdb it. I'm not so good at object analysis though.

Comment: I see a **trietool.c** in the library package. Compile it with library and attach the resulting binary with GDB for debugging.

Comment: what means? How can compile it with library?I compile it using the default makefile.trietool-0.2 seems a shell scripte,not binary file.